# How to get multi-tenant Rails app / ActiveRecord to store date/time for tenants in different zones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, timezone, rails-activerecord, multi-tenant

I have a Rails application that serves multiple tenant applications.  These tenants can exist in different time zones, e.g. New York and LA.  These tenant applications process payments and send data to my application.  I am using PostgreSQL.

The data being sent is timestamped and includes the offset for the timezone in which the tenant exists.  When my application receives and saves this data, ActiveRecord converts it to UTC without the offset.

Is it possible to configure ActiveRecord to preserve the timezone offset when the data is saved to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Save datetime in utc always.
Whenever displaying the timestamp in views use

```
@post.created_at.in_time_zone(current_site.timezone)
```

current_site.timezone should return the timezone string corresponding to location.